# How to show a selection of image in grid view in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can I show selection of an image in grid view at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643547/how-can-i-show-selection-of-an-image-in-grid-view-at-once)

I have a question that I want a check mark image shows when we select an image from grid view in the middle of the image, means suppose when we click on a grid item then a check mark image will appear in the middle of the image which shows the selection of image.

For Example below are showing the iphone screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the position of the clicked image by making the position final and adding an onClick listener to the imageView.  This logs the position of the image that was clicked.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ImageView imageView;
  if (convertView == null) {  
    // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);


    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d("onClick","position ["+position+"]");
      }

    });

  } 
  else {
    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
  }

  imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
  return imageView;
}
```

or use this :
For a GridView you can use the setOnItemClickListener method to have an OnItemClickListener listener. That listener will give you a method that you must override with the signature

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
```

where you get the position of the item in the grid that was clicked and the View that is inside the cell of the grid. Is that what you need?

Comment: share your XML too.. @Rizvan

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it with `GridView`.

For implementing this kind of functionality, you have to define **custom adapter** for the same. Define a raw layout file with `ImageView` and `CheckBox` and inflate the same inside the GridView.

**raw_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/thumbImage" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is a detailed example with the same functionality: [**`Android custom image gallery with checkbox in grid to select multiple`**](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/)
.

Comment: Thanks paresh for your valuable comment but I don't want the same, I just want when user click on particular image in grid view then check mark image is displayed in the center of the image, as it is the shared image in my question.

Comment: @SanatPandey Don't like to give your try on this example?

Answer (score 1):

Make a GridView and inside that use a custom inflated layout like

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/image_view" />
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/check_image" android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```