# how can I show selection of an image in grid view at once

Tags: android

I have a question that I have a custom grid view in which two images one is the background image and second is the check mark image, when I clicked on one Item of grid view check mark shows which presents selection of image but when we want to select a second item of grid view it also shows check marks on the same image as shown in an below attached image, but I want that only one image can be selected at once, means if one is selected other checkmarks will goes to be hidden. Please suggest me the right result.

[image]

**Code:**
**GridAdapter:**

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    ArrayList<Integer> items = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int checked=0;
    public GridAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Integer> items) {
        activity = a;
        this.items = items;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      //  View v = convertView;
          ImageView img;
        final ImageView img_select;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_items, null);
            img_select = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_image);
            img_select.setTag(position);
            img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_GridItem);
            img.setTag(position);
            //img_select = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);

            img.setBackgroundResource(items.get(position));


            img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("Clicked", "Tag###########");
                //img_select.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                img_select.setFocusable(true);
                img_select.setEnabled(true);
                if(checked==0)
                {

                img_select.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selectimage);
                GreetingTextContainer greet = GreetingTextContainer.getSingletonObject();
                greet.setPosition(position);
                checked =1;
                }
                else
                {
                    img_select.setBackgroundResource(0);
                    checked=0;
                }
            }
        });
        }



        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show a selection of image in grid view in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641403/how-to-show-a-selection-of-image-in-grid-view-in-android)

Comment: Do *not* post duplicate questions on the same topic.  Granted, this is a slight modification, but it is *so* slight that it doesn't warrant a *completely new* question.  I've closed the original as a duplicate of this, since *this* is really the intended behavior that was being sought.  However, Stack Overflow is not your crowd-sourced incremental development team, please don't treat it as such with duplicates with trivial edits.

Comment: `GreetingTextContainer` what does this class do. can you post the code please.

Comment: Thanks for the question, helped me much

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is one simple way to do this. You can keep reference of previously selected item. e.g. you make a variable at class level, where you are using the adapter. Then in your onClick listener, you un-select that image and set that variable with the current view(current image). e.g.

```
ImageView iv_selected = null;

// ..........

@Override
public void onClick(View view) 
{
     Log.i("Clicked", "Tag###########");
     if(iv_selected != null)
     {
          // unselect the image here
     }
     // set this variable again e.g.
     iv_selected = (ImageView)view;


     //img_select.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     img_select.setFocusable(true);
     img_select.setEnabled(true);
     if(checked==0)
     {

          img_select.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selectimage);
          GreetingTextContainer greet = GreetingTextContainer.getSingletonObject();
          greet.setPosition(position);
          checked =1;
     }
     else
     {
          img_select.setBackgroundResource(0);
          checked=0;
     }
}
```

in this you'll always have the refernce of the single selected ImageView. So, you can uncheck it when you select something else. I hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you forgot to unselect all images except the current selected image. only you have done is setting background for selected image. you need to set unseleted images for others aswell

**Step-1**initialize selected position as -1 in GridAdapter class

```
int checked=0;
int selectedPosition = -1;
```

**Step-2**rewrite your onclick method as given below

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Log.i("Clicked", "Tag###########");
         //img_select.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         img_select.setFocusable(true);
         img_select.setEnabled(true);


        if(checked==0)
        {
            selectedPosition = position;

        }
        for(int i = 0; i<items.size(); i++){
            if(i == selectedPosition){
                img_select.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selectimage);
                GreetingTextContainer greet = GreetingTextContainer.getSingletonObject();
                greet.setPosition(position);
                checked =1;
            }else{
                 img_select.setBackgroundResource(0);
                 checked=0;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in your overrided method onItemClick

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p, View view, int position,
                        long id) {
                    pos=position;
                    for(int i=0;i<ur_imageList.size();i++){
                        if(i==position){
                            //do nothing
                        }
                        else{
                            ur_imageList.get(i).isSelected=false;
                        }
                    }
                    if(ur_imageList.get(position).isSelected){//To deselect If selected
                        ur_imageList.get(position).isSelected=false;
                    }
                    else{   
                        ur_imageList.get(position).isSelected=true;
                    }
                    gridview.invalidateViews();
                }
            });
```