# android show Image Selection in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I am developing a kind of gallery app in android and I want to show images to be selected from `GridView.`

I am getting images from SD card of device and I am using `CustomAdapter` for selecting images.

Here is my `CustomGridAdapter.java`

```
private class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String[] items;
    MainActivity context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomGridAdapter(MainActivity context, String[] items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);
        }

        final ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path + "/" + items[position] + "/off.png");
        img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                context.itemClicked(position);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the exact problem? You don't seem to be asking anything.

Comment: I just want to display image selection in GridView

Comment: I think it is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641403/how-to-show-a-selection-of-image-in-grid-view-in-android]. Hope you will get required solution.

Comment: I've tried this from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910477/change-background-colour-of-image-on-selection-in-gridview)
but it not changes the background of other image when selecting other image...

Comment: Maintain Data model separate from the view model.. It will work fine then.. :)